# URL rewriter and Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, url

I have a url that uses https.  My client would like to be able to avoid typing https everytime so i was looking in to using URL rewriter 2  to rewrite the URL so that

http://x.com -> https://x.com

I have tried following two How-tos but neither seems to redirect.  Can someone step me through the setup with IIS 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about doing something like this...

Force SSL on the site, and redirect users who get an error on the non-SSL site.

http://www.servicefirstsupport.com/KB/a178/how-do-i-force-https-redirect-in-iis.aspx

http://www.jppinto.com/2009/04/automatically-redirect-http-requests-to-https-iis-7/

Answer (score 6):

Not really an answer (not an answer you want to hear anyway) but.. I'm no fan of these redirects. Its healthy for the user to be observant regarding when a page is secure and when it is not.

Also several SSL exploits takes advantage of HTTP > HTTPS redirects to hijack session and perform man in the middle attacks, so my answer would be to talk your customer out of it from a security POV :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a good tutorial of how to coexist HTTP and HTTPS. It point out some problems like the cookie which is not shared. You might take a look.

http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/mixed-http-and-https-content-with-sharepoint-2010/

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/mixed-http-and-https-content-with-sharepoint-2010/) is a page which I used to accomplish this, step "4. Redirecting users to Http or Https". It uses the URL Rewrite module you mention.

Another series of post which might be very useful in [SharePoint Config](http://www.sharepointconfig.com/tag/ssl/).